# Could not resolve entry module "src/index.html" when using vite to build react

Tags: reactjs, vite

when I am using this command to using vite `v4.3.5` to build a react project that was created by create-react command:

```
> tsc && vite build

vite v4.3.5 building for production...
✓ 0 modules transformed.
✓ built in 6ms
Could not resolve entry module "src/index.html".
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "src/index.html".
    at error (file:///Users/john/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2125:30)
    at ModuleLoader.loadEntryModule (file:///Users/john/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23959:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

this is the `vite.config.ts` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    plugins: [react()],
})
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `vite.config.ts` file looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

And if you run the build script with `npm run build`, it works because the `index.html` file is at the root-level directory of the project.

```
rootDir/
  |- src/
      |- <src dir contents>
  |- index.html
  |- vite.config.ts
```

By passing a `root` property like this `root: path.join(__dirname, 'src')` you are asking for an `index.html` file that is placed **inside** the `src` directory which - provided that you have not modified the initial file structure of the project - does not exist.