# [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/src/main.tsx"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I have a legacy typescript react app, now I want to migration it from webpack to vite, when I using this command to build the app, show error like this:

```
> tsc && vite build

vite v4.3.5 building for production...
✓ 2 modules transformed.
✓ built in 32ms
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/src/main.tsx" from "/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/src/index.html".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/src/main.tsx" from "/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/src/index.html".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
    at viteWarn (file:///Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.3.5_@types+node@16.18.23/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:46561:23)
    at onwarn (file:///Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react/dist/index.mjs:237:9)
    at onRollupWarning (file:///Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.3.5_@types+node@16.18.23/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:46582:9)
    at onwarn (file:///Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.3.5_@types+node@16.18.23/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:46332:13)
    at Object.onwarn (file:///Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.21.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25305:13)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.21.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23940:26)
    at file:///Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/snap-web/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.21.5/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23900:26
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

what should I do to fixed this problem? I have searching from internet seems no-one facing the similar issue. this is the `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    plugins: [react()],
    build:{
        outDir: "build"
    }
})
```

this is the main.tsx which I was pasted from the standard lib that create from command `npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template react-ts`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <div>ddddd</div>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

this is the `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76207937/could-not-resolve-entry-module-src-index-html-when-using-vite-to-build-react/76208327#76208327), the default `vite.config.ts` file looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

And if you run the build script with `npm run build`, it works because the `index.html` file is at the root-level directory of the project.

```
rootDir/
  |- src/
      |- <src dir contents>
  |- index.html
  |- vite.config.ts
```

By passing a `root` property like this `root: path.join(__dirname, 'src')` you are asking for an `index.html` file that is placed **inside** the `src` directory.

Now, since you are migrating from webpack, you probably have the `index.html` file *inside* the `src` directory and you tried to modify the `root` in the `vite.config.ts` to find the correct entry point.
However, the vite `index.html` file is linked to the `main.tsx` file like this

```html
<script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
```

All you need to do is change the file structure to be identical to the one that vite would provide you with by default:

Change your `vite.config.ts` file to this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build:{
    outDir: "build"
  }
})
```

And then move the `index.html` file to the **root directory**.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve  this issue, check your file extension under the component folder . In Vite your component file extension should be .tsx

*